# Send dynamic LIs into mySQL table with php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am messing around with this list app / list generator, and I have a question about sending some of the information to the mySQL table I created for it.

So the app generates via jQuery a new ***li*** for every item and qty. added into a ***ul*** with an id of list-a. Then it also generates a new ***li*** for the price of the item into an ***ul*** with an id of list-b. All this is working fine.

Below the created List you can save the list in order to retrieve it at a later time. I have the "List Name" field, "Username" field and "Password" field working and sending the accurate info to the db, but none of the newly generated ***lis***  get inserted to the db. I tried to wrap the ***uls*** in a **form** with the same method/action and didn't work.

Here is the working app.
http://codepen.io/Simetria/pen/YPGqMa

The php code without posting the ***lis***:

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', '************');
define('DB_USER', '************');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '************');
define('DB_HOST', '************');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$list_name = $_POST['listname'];
$user_name = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$add_listname = "INSERT INTO mylist_add (listname, user, password) VALUES ('$list_name', '$user_name', '$password')";

if (!mysql_query($add_listname)) {
    die('ERROR: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

mysql_close();
?>

Any idea how I can grab those jQuery generated ***li***s and insert them into the table?

Thanks SO much for y'all help.

Sergio

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are selecting any of your list items. The script you linked is just getting the specific fields you passed in. Also, the list attributes need to be sent over in an array or a group of objects. You could grab $_POST['list_a'] from the looks of your current setup and then manipulate the data in php to exclude the html

Edit: On another note please look into PHP PDO. Passing in user input directly into your database without sanitizing it first can lead to sql injections.

Comment: Hi Karrde00, yes i tried to include the LIs in the php in a few different ways, but reverted back so the code was not full of errors. And yes, it's not a real thing, so security is not a big deal. How would I grab the ['list_a']? As a variable?

Comment: You will need to use php's strip_tags function to remove the tags before you put them in the database. What does your table look like and what errors are you getting?

Comment: I have a row for list-a and a row for list-b and a AI id. Also a row for the other fields. But thinking a bit ahead do you think grabbing the UL will be a good idea in order to retrieve the list later and display it in a similar stylized way as when the list was created? BTW...Thank you!!

Comment: You should make another table for the lists and then combine them using a foreign key. This will make it easier to reference. Or are you trying to just take all the html and save it in the database as well? Typically you only save data in the database. That way you can manipulate the way it looks as you want to. Although if you really want it to be exactly the same then you should save all the HTML from around it. Just be sure to run sanitize functions on it

Comment: I thought about that... and you're right it would be easier to reference. I don't need the html - just the data. Sorry for my ignorance, but is there a way in php to grab the data from each list item generated and save them into its own row in the db? Thanks again.

Comment: Use a for each loop and then you can call the function strip_tags to remove all php/HTML tags from the lists. This should get you just the data inside. I would recommend using print_r on one of the lists so you can see the structure of the data